# Is there a way to tell Google Cloud Dataflow that the data coming in is already ordered?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have an input data source that is approximately 90 GB (it can be either a CSV or XML, it doesn't matter) that contains an already ordered list of data. For simplicity, you can think of it as having two columns: time column, and a string column. The hundreds of millions of rows in this file are already ordered by the time column in ascending order.

In our Google cloud DataFlow, we have modeled each row as an element in our Pcollection, and we apply DoFn transformations to the string field (e.g. count the number of characters that are uppercase in the string etc.). This works fine.

However, we then need to apply functions that are supposed to be calculated for a block of time (e.g. five minutes) with a one minute overlap. So,  we are thinking about using a  sliding windowing function (even though the data is bounded).

However, the calculations logic that needs to be applied over these five-minute windows  assumes that the data is ordered logically ( i.e. ascending)  by the time field. My understanding is that even when using these windowing functions, one cannot assume that within each window the P collection objects are ordered in any way – so one would need to manually iterate through every P collection and reorder them, right? However, this seems like a huge waste of computational power, since the incoming data already contains ordered data. So is there a way to  teach/inform Google cloud data flow that the input data is ordered and so to maintain that order even within the windows?

On a minor note, I had another question: my understanding is that if the data source is unbounded, there is never a "overall aggregation" function that would ever execute, as it never really make sense (since there is no end to the incoming data); however, if one uses a windowing function for bounded data, there is a true end  state which corresponds to when all the data has been read from the CSV file. Therefore, is there a way to tell Google cloud data flow  to do a final calculation once all the data has  been read in, even though we are using a windowing function to divide the data up?

Answer (score 3):

SlidingWindows sounds like the right solution for your problem.  The ordering of the incoming data is not preserved across a GroupByKey, so informing Dataflow of that would not be useful currently.  However, the batch Dataflow runner does already sort by timestamp in order to implement windowing efficiently, so for simple windowing like SlidingWindows, your code will see the data in order.

If you want to do a final calculation after doing some windowed calculations on a bounded data set, you can re-window your data into the global window again, and do your final aggregation after that:

```
p.apply(Window.into(new GlobalWindows()));
```